# How to get past command prompt hang without manually hitting enter? [Python - Selenium]

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, error-handling, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to webscrape with python via selenium, and for one of the websites, after scraping the information this error pops up:

`[11796:3768:0425/173530.772:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(135)] Invalid entry with unique id: 35`

A similar error happens when I try to log in to a website(https://www.waug.com/good/?idx=104880) via selenium. My code is:

```
import selenium.webdriver
option = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_argument(' - incognito')
browser = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('https://www.waug.com/good/?idx=104880')
browser.find_element_by_name('btn-login').click()
browser.find_element_by_id('mem_id').send_keys(myID)
browser.find_element_by_id('mem_pwd').send_keys(myPW)
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("button[type='submit']").click()
```

Then I get the error: `[11364:1060:0425/175320.588:ERROR:navigation_entry_screenshot_manager.cc(135)] Invalid entry with unique id: 5`

Now the real problem is that when I get these errors, the program doesn't break but my command prompt just hangs until I manually hit enter. Is there a way to make my program hit enter on its own to get past this error? I'm scraping a bunch of similar websites and I don't want the program to wait for me to hit enter manually before continuing on.  For now I don't care too much about why the error is popping up(although it'd be great to know if anyone does know), so maybe is there a way to suppress the error over all?

Comment: Your binary versions please

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry - I have no idea what that means ! :(

Comment: I am asking for the information regarding Selenium/WebDriver/WebBrowser versioning information